# JSP hosting on Google App Engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsp

Any body hosted JSP in GoogleAppEngine...
I Expect the user experiences from GoogleAppEngine

Is it easy to maintain JSP/Servlet .
I have used another free webhosting service. But it wasn't nice to manage and use.

Comment: Please rephrase your question. It's like a question with the title "C?".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSP and Servlet is still JSP and Servlet on Google App Engine. I have used it to call the Twitter API from the servlet and store it in their Memcache. It was just like writing any other application. However, when you deploy it, either it just works or you have no clue whats gone wrong. Bottomline - its very easy as long as it just works.

Answer (score 4):

JSPs are [a standard part](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/usingjsps.html) of the Java GAE. So what exactly is you question?

What do you mean by your second sentence?

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented an application based on a simple servlet serving JSON and storing/loading data directly using DataStore API (no JDO, JPA)

Comment: I'm feeling fine, thank you :)